# Is there a way to use flutter web and connect to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, flutter, flutter-web

Is there a way to use flutter web and connect to a MySQL database? Right now I'm using the mysql1 package to do this for all other platforms and it works great.

Comment: Probably not, browsers can only do HTTP.

Comment: https://santosenoque-ss.medium.com/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-mysql-web-server-and-phpmyadmin-e100f47bfb82

check this medium article hopes it may help